# Save/Get raw audio from IPhone over bluetooth or USB into macOS

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, audio, mirroring

I am trying to mirror audio from IPhone and get in it raw form in macOS so I can redirect this audio into another application given the condition that the IPhone audio is undisturbed (basically TAP the audio).

I tried [QuickTime Video Hack](https://github.com/danielpaulus/quicktime_video_hack) but I ran into segmentation with libusb package.

Upon looking into issues over the repository, I found someone raising the same issue. However, it was overcome by using older version of libusb 1.0.20 but that version is not listed into brew anymore.
I tried using raw github link for download but ran into another error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.